# Puppeteer - How to use userDataDir in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

This puppeteer scripts works fine running locally, however does not utilize the userDataDir when running on Cloud Functions. I've tried all combinations of initializing userDataDir.

Update:

Folder Structure:

```
Functions
├── index.js
│   ├── userDataDir
```

index.js:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const path = require("path");

exports.testPupFunction = functions
  .region("us-west1")
  .runWith({ memory: "1GB", timeoutSeconds: 60 })
  .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      args: [
        `--user-data-dir=${path.resolve(__dirname, "./userDataDir")}`,
         `--user-data-dir=${path.resolve(__dirname, "userDataDir")}`,
        `--user-data-dir=./userDataDir`,

        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--no-sandbox"
      ],
      userDataDir: "./userDataDir"
      userDataDir: "userDataDir"
    });
  try {
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setViewport({ width: 800, height: 600 });

      const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

      await page.goto("stackoverflow.com", {
        waitUntil: "networkidle0"
      });
      await delay(1000);
      const buffer = await page.screenshot({ fullPage: true });
      res.type("image/png").send(buffer);
    } catch (e) {
      await browser.close();
      res.status(500).send(e.toString());
    }
    await browser.close();
  });
```

Any ideas how to fix? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to illustrate exactly what you're deploying that shows the requested data dir should be available at runtime.  If you didn't deploy it, it won't be available.

Comment: Done. That might be it - I'm simply deploying it (meaning it's included in the folder that I "firebase deploy") & adding the --user-data-dir args.

Comment: The Firebase CLI will package up the entire contents of the "functions" folder and make all that available to the function at runtime.  I would expect that `__dirname` is the root of that deployment, and you should be able to read those files.  Try writing some code in the function (using node's `fs` module) to make sure you can read the expected files individually to make sure they exist

Comment: I used the fs module to list all files in directory & can confirm that userDataDir is there! I also tried creating a ```tmp``` folder & putting the folder in there, that also didn't work.

Comment: Dump your `args` and see if it contains exactly what you expect?  At this point you are basically just debugging.